# How can I check write access to a remote Git repository ("can I push?")

Tags: git, github, git-remote, ls-remote

I am building a (somewhat limited) Git client. To set up a repository, you enter the URL to the remote repo. I want to check whether the user has read+write access to that repository. If not, I present an authentication dialog.

I check **'read' access** with `git ls-remote <url>`.

Is there an analogous way to check **'write' access**, without cloning the repo first? (I know I could `git clone <url>` and then `git push --dry-run`)

Comment: Well, technically to push a commit into a repo you don't need to clone it first. But remember that pushing a chain of commits and update remote references are two different operations and you may have a permission for the former, but no permission for the latter. Also certain references could be unmodifiable.

Comment: 'git push --dry-run' is mentioned in this post as a way to check write access, when you have cloned. however for some of my remotes, this opens a password prompt & hangs indefinitely. there doesn't seem to be a non-interactive way to check if you have write access, even if you do have a clone of the repo. how can i check write access to a git repository, if i do have a clone of it?

Comment: A very easy way to check is whether you see an edit 'pencil' icon in the top right of the README.MD on the main Code page of the repo (scroll down to it if there's a long list of top level files/folders). Do this when you are logged in to Github, obviously.

Answer (score 153):

If the git repo is in github, open any file in the repo, then click 'edit',
github will show something like this:

> You’re editing a file in a project you don’t have write access to. We’ve created a fork of this project for you to commit your proposed changes 
>   to. Submitting a change to this file will write it to a new branch in 
>   your fork, so you can send a pull request.enter code here

Comment: You're not wrong -- Github does indeed show this behaviour. However, the OP asked for something analogous to `git ls-remote` that their new tool could use, so the Github web UI probably wouldn't suit them.

Comment: There are more git repositories than just github repositories ;)

Comment: Regarding the GUI, the tooltip can also indicate whether you can "Edit" or "Fork then edit" if no access. This is true with both Github proper and GH Enterprise.

Comment: Forking a repo copies the entire repo, right? The repo could be very large. That seems like a pretty hefty operation just to check what your access level is...

Comment: @KyleDelaney You don't need to click on the edit button, just hover over it. It will show "Edit this file" or "Edit the file in your fork of this project" depending on whether you have write access or not.

Answer (score 19):

With the latest GitHub API you can check the [permissions on a particular repo](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/collaborators#get-repository-permissions-for-a-user) for a USERNAME (yours or another user) with the following command (you'll need to authenticate using your_username and [your_personal_access_token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)) e.g.:

```
curl -u your_username:your_personal_access_token \
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
 https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/collaborators/USERNAME/permission
```

The response will show what permissions the USERNAME has for that repo.

Otherwise it can report:

```json
{
"message": "Not Found"
}
```

Or if you don't have push access to the repo in question or it will fail with:

```json
{
  "message": "Must have push access to view collaborator permission.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-permissions-for-a-user"
}
```

Comment: If you have the Github CLI, it's even easier: `gh api repos/octocat/hello-world/collaborators/USERNAME/permission`

Answer (score 8):

Literally just push (with no changes). Git needs credentials even just to attempt a push and report that it's unnecessary.

With correct credentials set up:

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

after messing up my ssh config:

```
$ git push
ERROR: Permission to [some repo] denied to [my user name].
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: This is easily the best answer! It works for any Git repo (not just GitHub) and doesn't create any dummy commits/branches. Just make sure your local branch is level with the remote before you push otherwise you might push an unwanted extra commit.

Comment: Yeah just tried it and though my error message looks a bit different this seems to be the only real answer to the original question with no side effects or github specific dependency

Answer (score 3):

Push a harmless branch to the server:

```bash
git clone (...)
git branch -a
# Make sure no branch named "test" exists. If it does, use another name.

git branch test
git push -u origin test
# If the above push worked, you have write access

# Cleaning up
git branch -d test
git push -d origin test # only run this if you do have write access
```

Answer (score 1):

Go the branch that you want to edit and hover over the edit button and it might say "Fork this repository and edit this file", if you have no access to the repository.
But suppose you have some access to the repository, then the hover message will show "Edit this file", but you might not have access to commit to the branch. To check access to a particular branch, you can click on the edit button and on the submit changes form,you will see "Commit changes", if you have access. Or if you don't have access, you will see "Propose Changes" as it will create a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

You may perform `git push git+ssh://host.org/path/to/repo some_ref` without cloning.

But remember that pushing a chain of commits and update remote references are two different operations and you may have a permission for the former, but no permission for the latter. Also certain references could be unmodifiable.

Comment: This method would work from a working directory with a ref. Is there a way to do this without setting up a dummy repo and creating a commit first?

Comment: Yeah, who wants all these random dummy commits? Isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: Haven't tried this myself, but perhaps the `--dry-run` parameter could be used to test for push access without pushing a real commit? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---dry-run

Comment: `--dry-run` can't be used for this purpose. Check this answer for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403573/how-can-one-dry-run-a-git-push-to-check-whether-one-has-write-permissions-to-a-r

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gh` (GitHub CLI)'s `api` subcommand to check your access to a repo (you need to use `gh auth login` to login to your GitHub account first).

The command is

`gh api /repos{/owner}{/repo}/collaborators/USERNAME/permission`

This will give you the lots of info.

If you want a command to output either just `read` or `write`, run this:

`gh api /repos{/owner}{/repo}/collaborators/USERNAME/permission | jq '.permission' -r`

Answer (score 0):

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git push --dry-run &>/dev/null
```

- `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0`: fail if you are required to enter credentials manually.
- `git push`: try to push changes to origin.
- `--dry-run`: simulate the operation, but don't perform it.
- `&>/dev/null`: silence any output.