# How can one dry run a git push to check whether one has write permissions to a remote?

Tags: git, user-permissions

Is there a way to dry run a `git push` to know whether the user has permissions to actually create a new remote branch? I'd like to be able to verify that all is good in regards to permissions for a bunch of repos where the user will attempt to create new branches before they are actually created so that I can dry run the full execution before actually doing it.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3636914/1860929) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3636939/1860929) on it.

Comment: same question, newer answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29801749/1875965

Comment: A github only answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65683358/99717

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Shawn Pierce [wrote](https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss/c/g5iz84EbSz4/m/jOmAx0F9vVAJ)  the following about `git push --dry-run`:

> A `--dry-run` doesn't send the commands the client would use from client
> to server, so the server can't tell the client if it would accept them
> or not. The entire `--dry-run` thing is **client side only**.

(my emphasis)

So, if there is a way to check whether one has write permissions to a remote, `git push --dry-run` is definitely not it.

---

Clarification by [@RobArthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5861450/rob-arthan): `--dry-run` is **read-only at the remote**: it checks whether the remote has changes that you don't have locally but doesn't send any updates to the the remote.

Comment: Just a comment, in case anyone else was slightly misled by the above, as I was. git push --dry-run does everything except actually sending the updates, in particular, it does check to see whether the remote has changes that you don't have locally (as I have just confirmed by experiment). So it is a bit misleading to say it is a client side only operation - it does access the remote, but it doesn't try to update it.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for you comment. Feel free to update the answer, with relevant links to the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Posting as an answer on the test I did where I don't think it works in my scenario. I'm creating a branch form another one without further changes

```
git clone ....
git checkout master
git branch -f test master
git push --dry-run origin test
```

and it passed even though I have zero push permissions on this server/repo combo

```
To ssh://<server>/repo
 * [new branch]      test -> test
```

Pushing without dry-run hits the error condition I was expecting

```
git push origin test
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://<server>/repo
 ! [remote rejected] test -> test (can not create new references)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<server>/repo'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `git push` docs @ https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push --dry-run apears as an option:

```
git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [--follow-tags] 
[--atomic] [-n | --dry-run ] ... (more flags)
```

It usually means that the commands are handled as usual by the server, except that the data is not modified, that is, nothing is changed.
It is useful for testing critical commands, because the output logged by the server is (almost) equal to that of a "wet" run.