# How do I view my permissions for a particular Git repo?

Tags: github, permissions

I was wondering in GitHub, how do I view the permissions I have to a particular repository?  If the URL is

```
https://github.com/org/repo
```

Where can I find out what (if any) permission I have?

Answer (score 7):

If the git repo is in github, open any file in the repo, then click 'edit', github will show something like this:

> You’re editing a file in a project you don’t have write access to. We’ve created a fork of this project for you to commit your proposed changes to. Submitting a change to this file will write it to a new branch in your fork, so you can send a pull request.enter code here

Refer to this link:

[How can I check write access to a remote Git repository ("can I push?")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811045/how-can-i-check-write-access-to-a-remote-git-repository-can-i-push)

Answer (score 3):

**To check for which of the repositories you have access to (i.e. both forked and non forked)**

Click on profile -> Settings -> Repositories

https://github.com/settings/repositories

Comment: I believe the original poster was asking about *any* GitHub repo, not just ones you own or that you have forked.

Comment: This is useful because it shows repositories I have access to even if I can't view the settings from the repository itself. I can't remember which repositories I have accepted an invitation to but this seems to include those. But it doesn't show full detail. Where do you look for this information, @dave_k_smith ?