# Is it possible to know whether the user who cloned the repository has write access or not?

Tags: git, github

I'm using GitHub. Let's say John has read access to `git@github.com:Org/Repo` and Jack has read and write access.

I want to create a small tool to facilitate some git operations.

I want to know whether the user who has cloned the repo has write access or not.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

I searched but I could not find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+check+user+has+write+access

Comment: Esp. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65683358/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73898031/7976758